# How does the PS4 internal fans work to cool down the PS4 after closing a game?

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

I live in a place with high temperature and I don't know how to cool down my PS4 after I finish playing, so I have various questions and scenarios about how the internal fans of the PS4 works in Rest mode and how they work in the PlayStation XMB menu.

Questions:

1) Are the PS4 internal fans turned on during rest mode?.

2) What's the speed of the PS4 internal fans during rest mode are the same or higher than normal XMB mode?

Scenario 1:
   I leave the PS4 cool down 15 minutes in the XMB menu after playing for 2 hours and then switched it to rest mode for 30 min, and then turn off the console.

Scenario 2:
   I put the PS4 to rest mode right after finishing playing and not leave it in the XMB.

Last Question:

3) What would be the best scenario from the ones that I described to cool down my PS4?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes my PS4 would get hot. The fans would speed up during game-play to cool down the PS. The system is autonomous, if the internal CPU detects temperature going over certain Limit, it would boost up the fans to compensate.

1. So far I haven't had my fans turned on while the PS is resting no, BUT the PS would dial up the speed when i set it to rest, sometimes have it going for few minutes before calming down.
2. As said before, it depends on the temperature. In my experience, I'd play a game with low speed, then in the middle of the game, it would go to mid-high. Then when i set it to turn off it would go to high for few minutes.

Play your games and don't bother about the cooling down. The system is smart enough to know if it needs to have the fans on or off at any given time.

In conclusion its worth mentioning that the optimal working temperature for a system (CPU. GPU) is not something that me and you might consider normal. 60 Degrees is completely in the realm of good temperatures for a CPU to work at, and is even preferable than say 20 as that how CPUs work better and is not worth going into detail right now.

Comment: Good answer you should also mention having adequate airflow around the case.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure about the fans max RPM, they are indeed automatic and will spin up or down depending on the system temperature. This also happens during rest mode.

I would like to warn though, that if they are running high and noisily, don't unplug the system to make them stop - this could melt your ps4. Let them run so the system can cool down.

If you want your system less noisy overall, make sure there's a lot of air flow around it.